# PHP Google Maps Search Error?

Tags: php, xml, google-maps

I have been trying to follow this old Google tutorial (could be the problem)

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

But for some reason I cannot see the xml file? I know it is connecting to the database and selecting the correct table but my xml file just shows empty?

My database has data inside with the sample data google supplied.

http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~watfordy/googlemaps/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=25

Any Ideas why this is happening?

Thanks 
Brent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is data there, just not within a radius of 25:

http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~watfordy/googlemaps/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=25000

It even can be displayed on a [Google Maps API v3 map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http%3A%2F%2Fisca01.bigwavemedia.info%2F~watfordy%2Fgooglemaps%2Fphpsqlsearch_genxml.php%3Flat%3D37%26lng%3D-122%26radius%3D25000)